# A better way to handle asynchronous calls when using the AWS Java SDK V2 in Scala?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-java-sdk

### Background

A few days ago, version `2.1` of the AWS Java SDK was officially released. One of the main selling points is how it handles asynchronous calls vs the previous version of the SDK.

I decided to run some experiments using Scala and the new SDK and had a bit of a hard time trying to come up with an idiomatic way to deal with the Futures returned by the SDK.

### The Question

Is there a way I can do this better, more sucinctly, and with less boilerplate code?

### Objective

Deal with AWS SDK for Java V2 using Scala and be able to handle success and failures in an idiomatic way.

### The Experiment

Create an Async SNS Client and submit messages 500 asynchronously:

#### Experiment 1 - Use the `CompletableFuture` Returned by the SDK

```
  (0 until 500).map { i =>
    val future = client.publish(PublishRequest.builder().topicArn(arn).message(messageJava + i.toString).build())
    future.whenComplete((response, ex) => {
      val responseOption = Option(response) // Response can be null
      responseOption match {
        case Some(r) => println(r.messageId())
        case None => println(s"There was an error ${ex.getMessage}")
      }
    })
  }.foreach(future => future.join())
```

Here, I create a unique request and publish it. The `whenComplete` function turns the response into an option as this value can be null. This is ugly because the means of dealing with success/failure are bound on checking for null in the response.

#### Experiment 2 - Get the result inside a Scala Future

```
(0 until 500).map { i =>
    val jf = client.publish(PublishRequest.builder().topicArn(arn).message(messageScala + i.toString).build())
    val sf: Future[PublishResponse] = Future { jf.get }
    sf.onComplete {
      case Success(response) => print(response.messageId)
      case Failure(ex) => println(s"There was an error ${ex.getMessage}")
    }
    sf
  }.foreach(Await.result(_, 5000.millis))
```

Here I use the `.get()` method on the `CompletableFuture` that way I can just deal with the Scala Future.

#### Experiment 3 - Use the `Scala - Java8 - Compat` library convert the `CompletableFuture` to a `Future`

```
(0 until 500).map { i =>
    val f = client.publish(PublishRequest.builder().topicArn(arn).message(messageScala + i.toString).build()).toScala
    f.onComplete {
      case Success(response) =>
      case Failure(exception) => println(exception.getMessage)
    }
    f
  }.foreach(Await.result(_, 5000.millis))
```

This is by far my favorite implementation, except that I need to use a thrid party [**experimental** library](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat#scala-java8-compat--).

### Observations

- In general all these implementations performed roughly the same, with the `future.join()` being a tiny bit faster than the others.
- The time it took for these functions to initialize the client and publish 500 messages was around 2 seconds
- The sequential version of this code takes a little bit under 1 minute (55 seconds)
- You can see the complete code [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sSkL8UkGQCiZiXEqO9d1JA)

Comment: While the `scala-java8-compat` README still does state "The API is currently still experimental: we do not yet guarantee source or binary compatibility with future releases.", it is part of the Scala authors' work, and as such not really a third party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mentioned that you are happy with converting completablefuture to scala.future, just that you do not like to take a dependency on scala-java8-compat.

In this case, you can simply roll your own, and you only want java8 to scala:

```
object CompletableFutureOps {                                                                                                                                        

  implicit class CompletableFutureToScala[T](cf: CompletableFuture[T]) {                                                                                             
    def asScala: Future[T] = {                                                                                                                                       
      val p = Promise[T]()                                                                                                                                           
      cf.whenCompleteAsync{ (result, ex) =>                                                                                                                          
        if (result == null) p failure ex                                                                                                                             
        else                p success result                                                                                                                         
      }                                                                                                                                                              
      p.future                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                  
}

def showByExample: Unit = {
  import CompletableFutureOps._   
  (0 until 500).map { i =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     val f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() => i).asScala                                                                                                             
     f.onComplete {                                                                                                                                                     
       case Success(response)  => println("Success: " + response)                                                                                                        
       case Failure(exception) => println(exception.getMessage)                                                                                                         
     }                                                                                                                                                                  
     f                                                                                                                                                                  
  }.foreach(Await.result(_, 5000.millis))    
}
```